# Firefox 3.5.2 displays installed addons on every startup, is this normal?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I have an issue with Firefox 3.5.2 where on startup, it shows me the add-on panel with the message "X new add-ons have been installed." This happens on every startup, without having installed new add-ons since last startup.

I tried turning off the automatic update checks for installed add-ons on startup, but that didn't work.

Anybody knows how to disable the add-on pane on startup?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same thing happen for me, as well. It's not a normal behavior, so there are no settings to turn on or off.

Try reinstalling Firefox; that fixed it for me. It doesn't take long, so it shouldn't be a real problem.

Comment: Just did that, and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! I know how frustrating it is when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going all out and reinstalling Firefox, you could just delete your profile. If that does not work, then reinstall it.

Comment: Reinstalling Firefox is much less disruptive than deleting your profile.  Deleting your profile will lose your bookmarks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me after downgrading from 4.x to 3.6.16. The re-install of FireFox didn't work for me, but I found something else that did.

When the dialog comes up, if you look carefully you will notice that one of the add-ons will be slightly highlighted (it is very subtle). That is the problem one, for me it was RoboForm. Just uninstall and re-install that add-on and the dialog will stop appearing when you open FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I updated from 3.0 to 3.5 (I also had the 3.5 beta installed) and some of my addons did not have 3.5 versions. When they all were updated to work on 3.5, this problem went away.